# How to get response time of fetch in react native?

Tags: reactjs, time, fetch, native

I want to get time difference between a request & response. For example in below code what is time interval to complete the request ?

```
fetch(baseUrl+"recs/rech/non consulté")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setReclamations(json))
      .then(console.log(setReclamations))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Native or not, the answer remains the same.

```js
const start = new Date();

fetch(baseUrl+"recs/rech/non consulté")
      .then((response) => {console.log(new Date() - start); return response.json()})
      .then((json) => {console.log(new Date() - start); return setReclamations(json)})
      .then(console.log(setReclamations))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
```

Each new console.log will show the difference between then and the moment just before the fetch was run.